# Environment variable does not work in path

Tags: c#

I'm trying to delete a directory in C# however nothing seems to happen. My code looks like this:

```cs
private void CacheClear_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

     string path = @"%LOCALAPPDATA%\FiveM\FiveM Application Data\data\cache";

     System.IO.DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(@"%LOCALAPPDATA%\FiveM\FiveM Application Data\data\cache");

     if(Directory.Exists(path)) di.Delete(true);
}
```

When I click my button nothing just happens, I don't get any errors.

Thanks,
Ossie

Answer (score 2):

Environment variables aren't automatically expanded by C#. You need to use [`Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.expandenvironmentvariables?view=net-5.0)

```
string path = @"%LOCALAPPDATA%\FiveM\FiveM Application Data\data\cache";
string expandedPath = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(path);

System.IO.DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(expandedPath);

if(Directory.Exists(expandedPath)) di.Delete(true);
```

Alternatively, you can use [`Environment.GetFolderPath`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.getfolderpath?view=net-5.0) with `Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData` to get the value for `%LOCALAPPDATA%` and use that to build your path:

```
string localAppData = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData);
string path = Path.Combine(localAppData, @"FiveM\FiveM Application Data\data\cache");
```

Also note that you can check if the [directory exists](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directoryinfo.exists?view=net-5.0) from the `DirectoryInfo` entity. Therefore:

```
if(di.Exists) di.Delete(true);
```

Comment: I've done like this:
`string localAppData = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData);
string path = System.IO.Path.Combine(localAppData, @"FiveM\FiveM Application Data\data\cache");

System.IO.DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(path);
if(di.Exists) di.Delete(true);
`

However still, nothing happens.

Comment: @OssieFromDK I've just tested it and it works fine? Perhaps you haven't linked up your button event? Try setting a breakpoint on the `string localAppData =` line and then see if execution pauses there when you click the button.

Comment: It turns green or orange (I'm colorblind so I'm unsure image: https://i.imgur.com/i5Hq0Qn.png) and shows this: https://i.imgur.com/Yy7U31e.png

I haven't used breakpoints before, so I'm unsure of what is expected to be returned.

Comment: @Ossie A breakpoint just pauses the execution of the code. You can hover over variables to see what they hold, and step through execution line-by-line. See [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/navigating-through-code-with-the-debugger?view=vs-2019). I've tested the above code and can confirm that the `cache` folder gets deleted, so I don't know why it doesn't work for you.